# How to scrape content from other sites using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web-scraping

I am doing a NEWS site project in PHP and for this project I want to fetch content from other NEWS sites using jQuery/JavaScript. Is there any functions in jQuery which scrape content from other domain names?

And also I don't want to use huge server CPU, since it is a college server. Does using jQuery for scrapping content use huge CPU?

In Stack Overflow I read about `jQuery.get()` function, is it ok to use this function to scrape content from other sites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [Cross-Domain-Ajax JQuery Plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) you can do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://news.bbc.co.uk',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var headline = $(res.responseText).find('a.tsh').text();
        alert(headline);
    }
});
```

they're hijacking the ajax method to use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to grab the html and return it as JSON, then use that as a string to scrape the data. check out the [Jquery Cross-domain Ajax Guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. [The Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents this. To do this you need to do it on a server using XMLHTTP.

Comment: I hope XMLHTTP makes use of AJAX... can u please give me some tips about XMLHTTP...

Comment: No, it doesn't really. It's the underlying layer used by AJAX to open a connection to a server. In this case you are opening a server-to-server connection to request a page instead of a browser-to-server request.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the curl module in PHP to access the news site's rss feed to collect the news you want to embed.

Setup a cron process to periodically download the RSS feed to local storage and convert it into a format you can use for your site. This will help to keep the load on the server down as your gathering the news once instead of every time the page is accessed.

Comment: first i thought that before, but my project requirement is i want to use jquery...

Answer (score 0):

You can do Data scraping using CURL in PHP instead of jquery You can see the blog for Data scraping using CURL in PHP:
http://www.codefire.org/blogs/item/data-scraping-using-curl-in-php.html