# Manipulating Goodreads Add Book Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

```
  <div id="gr_add_to_books">
<div class="gr_custom_each_container_">
  <a href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/1499687117" style="border:none" target="_blank"><img alt="DEADWEIGHT" src="https://www.goodreads.com/images/atmb_add_book-70x25.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Dear experts

The above code is to be implemented via an html box on a Weebly Website.  However, the background colour of the iframe is white.  My website is black, and I don't know how to change that, the colour of the text, or anything, despite my efforts....

Could someone please educate me....

if you need to see the page, please go to [DEADWEIGHT](http://www.nicholasboydcrutchley.com/deadweight)

I am currently undertaking a short course but I am a bit behind in this coding.

Sincerely

Nicholas Boyd Crutchley

ps... i have now wrapped up in facebook button code... but can't get rid of white corners!  IT would be best to have the full iframe, as good reads intended, but with a black background....but would be very happy to be rid of white corners too.. looking good now

```
 `code` <iframe src="https://www.goodreads.com/book/add_to_books_widget/17608936?atmb_widget%5Bbutton%5D=atmb_widget_1.png&atmb_widget%5Bhide_friends%5D=on&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nicholasboydcrutchley.com%2Fdeadweight.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:70px; height:25px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

`code`

my thanks to @wavebound

Answer (score 0):

You may be stuck here. Setting the `background-color` property of the iframe's document.body using Firefox's inspector [worked for me](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8DUJxl7BvGtVkVRbXZFcl8wc2s/edit?pli=1), but doing so programmatically with jQuery [isn't working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Yup, i used the inspector element.... as i understand it, this is drawn from goodreads.... can't see how to mask it?

Comment: You could pull something off by using the method in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397199/how-to-scrape-content-from-other-sites-using-jquery). Basically, you pull in the html yourself from the iframe url *http://www.goodreads.com/book/add_to_books_widget/17608936?atmb_widget%5Bbutton%5D=atmb_widget_1.png&atmb_widget%5Bhide_friends%5D=on&referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nicholasboydcrutchley.com%2Fdeadweight.html* with jQuery ajax and then you get free rein to modify it. When I get home I could create a demonstration of it.