# Can I use JS in the browser to get a certain element's value from an external webpage (cross-domain)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping, cross-domain

Can I use only JavaScript/jQuery and Ajax in the browser to get a certain element's value from an external webpage (cross-domain)?

Something like basic scraping.

Answer (score 1):

Well the way I see it you have 2 options:

**AJAX**

Only if the webpage allows CORS.
In the developer tools (F12), go to the Network tab and look for the following header in the response header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

If you found it, you can go ahead and create an ajax request to it and parse your element however you like - You get the response as a string. You can use regex to find the relevant data.

**Backend Scraping**

You can send a request to your server, which will send a request to that webpage, parse the response and send the relevant data (Element value) back to the client. This way you avoid all CORS problems that browsers create.

Hope this helps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397199/how-to-scrape-content-from-other-sites-using-jquery

Comment: @KrzysztofKaźmierczak That's cool - but that's exactly implementing my second approach - just using Yahoo to do so :)

Comment: Correct! I just wanted to share it as there are some code examples, which might be useful. But your answer is absolutely correct! ;)